# Is Synchronized keyword available in apex?

Tags: apex

Simply the title is the question. If **synchronized** keyword available, any reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apex is not a multi-threaded language, so there's no reason to have a concept of synchronized methods. While multiple threads of apex can be run at the same time they do not share context (static variables, object references, anything really).

Comment: The only thing that could be synchronized is your data. And you can use FOR UPDATE keyword in your SOQL query to lock specific set of records. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm

Comment: I actually had a pretty good use case where I could use a mutex around parallel batch jobs. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/370709/how-to-know-when-the-last-batch-job-in-parallel-execution-finishes

Comment: Well, a mutex around org cache that each batch job reads/modifies in their `finish` method.