# How to know when the last batch job in parallel execution finishes?

Tags: apex, batch, asynchronous

I have an apex class that is executed in parallel by calling `Database.executeBatch()` in a loop, where each instance processes a chunk of a dataset.

After all the jobs that were executed finish I need to execute some apex.

My initial thought is to query the `AsyncApexJob` records in the `finish` method of each batch instance, then kick off the final apex when no other jobs exist.

I'm worried there's an edge case with the last 2 jobs calling `finish` at the same time and not calling the final apex action.

Is there a better way to know when all submitted jobs have finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking I can use the [Org cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_org_examples.htm) to put how many instances of the job were executed, then in the `finish` method I can create a platform event that invokes a trigger to update the number of jobs executing.

When that cache value reaches 0 in the trigger, I can execute the apex

Edit: This still isn't a 100% perfect solution because the trigger subscribed to the platform event could run in parallel and the platform cache does not have mutexes for reading/writing.

Instead of using the platform cache I may need to use a concrete object using `FOR UPDATE` to have a platform level mutex on the record to update the # of parallel jobs in a thread safe manner

Comment: assuming that no new set of batchables were launched before the last set finished

Comment: Yeah no issue there, this is another interesting read about thread safe reads/writes I might implement for this problem https://www.jamessimone.net/blog/joys-of-apex/creating-a-round-robin-assignment/

Comment: I was not aware of this blog.  Lot's of good stuff here that I need to study.  1000 thanks.